# how to change only clicked button color from collection of buttons in react-native

Tags: react-native

how to change only clicked button color from the collection of buttons in react-native by onPress.
Button Text Should also change by onPress.

***Sample Code***

```
export class App extends Component {

        changeColor() {
            // code here
        }

        render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.button_view}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeColor.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.button_text}>
                    Button 1
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeColor.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.button_text}>
                    Button 2
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.changeColor.bind(this)} style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={styles.button_text}>
                    Button 3
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked ,btw it`s a little long way;
First set a flag for each of them like:

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state={
    button_1 : false,
    button_2 : false,
    button_3 : false,
    button_4 : false,
  }
```

then,for each `Button` do this:

```
 <Button
      title="Button 1"
      color={this.state.button_1 ? "green" : "gray"}
      onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                       button_1: !this.state.button_1,
                       button_2: false,
                       button_3: false,
                       button_4: false
                         });
               }}
  />

 <Button
      title="Button 2"
      color={this.state.button_2 ? "green" : "gray"}
      onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                       button_1: false,
                       button_2: !this.state.button_2,
                       button_3: false,
                       button_4: false
                         });
               }}
  />
```

do this for text too,it will work

Answer (score 1):

From your code, it looks like all the buttons have the same styling, so I would create a custom button component and render it and pass a flag such as active and set it to true from parent component within the `changeColor()` method.
You can then have styling based on the active prop.
i.e: style={{ color: this.props.active? 'red' : 'white';}}